# Excel: Search for text value, when found list specific column value in that row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet "24 Hour Pool" that searches another worksheet "SSP" for the text "UPSD" in the G column, followed by anything else.

When found, I want it to list whatever is in column E in that row. So listing it for each hit should display several values.

I've messed around with several formulas and can't get anything to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post a broken formula, or the file, so we have more info. We can explain, but we don't know exactly what to fix

Comment: It would help to have a better view of the data, like a screenshot. You can use dummy text if it contains sensitive data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to modify this:

Say we data like this and we want to locate all the "UPSD" rows and retrieve all the column **E** values from these rows:

[image]

In **B1** enter:

```
=MATCH("UPSD",G:G,0)
```

to find the *first* "UPSD" row.  In **B2** enter:

```
=MATCH("UPSD",INDEX(G:G,B1+1):INDEX(G:G,9999),0)+B1
```

and copy downward.  This gets the second "UPSD" row by starting the next MATCH() just below the first.

Finally in **C1** enter:

```
=INDEX(E:E,B1)
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Comment: According to the OP, the text "UPSD" can be followed by "anything else", which, I assume, might be a number of another suite of letters. I'm not sure your technique would work then.

Comment: That example works great, but there was a bit I forgot. I need it to check the value of another column in that row for "Scheduled". So basically scanning the rows for "UPSD*" in one column and "Scheduled" in another and only matching if both are present.